# Achieving same abstraction by replacing JObject's implementation with System.Text.Json alternative

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I'm trying to improve [this wrapper](https://github.com/Marfusios/binance-client-websocket) by replacing the `Newtonsoft.Json` with `System.Text.Json` in its `BinanceWebSocketClient` class and more specifically the `HandleObjectMessage` method. It is a message handler, which is supposed to parse the JSON results returned by the [combined stream](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#general-wss-information).

> Combined stream events are wrapped as follows: {"stream":"","data":}

The *stream* field is telling us what the stream name is. For ex. *!miniTicker@arr*. And data is the actual data corresponding to the stream name.

The handler `HandleObjectMessage` must recognize the JSON returned and parse it to the corresponding stream name object. If it's a kline, it should parse it to the `KlineResponse` class and so on.

### [GitHub (original HandObjectMessage)](https://github.com/Marfusios/binance-client-websocket/blob/master/src/Binance.Client.Websocket/Client/BinanceWebsocketClient.cs#L154)

### [GitHub (original BookTickerResponse)](https://github.com/Marfusios/binance-client-websocket/blob/master/src/Binance.Client.Websocket/Client/BinanceWebsocketClient.cs#L154)

Here are my changes to `System.Text.Json`. This is what I want to be reviewed. There were developers who actually used `switch` like [here](https://github.com/JuliaZaborowska/TPUM/blob/0bb2ed8583223187c695b8f6cf9c1312b4ddd689/TPUM/PresentationLayer/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs#L210) instead of that abstraction.

```cs
public class BookTickerResponse : ResponseBase<BookTicker>
{
    internal static bool TryHandle(JsonDocument response, ISubject<BookTickerResponse?> subject)
    {
        var stream = response.RootElement.GetProperty("stream").GetString() ?? string.Empty;

        if (!stream.ToLower().EndsWith("@bookTicker"))
            return false;

        var parsed = response.ToObject<BookTickerResponse>();

        subject.OnNext(parsed);

        return true;
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class BinanceWebSocketClient : IDisposable
{
    ...

    private bool HandleObjectMessage(string msg)
    {
        using var response = JsonDocument.Parse(msg);

        // Add object handlers
        return
            AggregateTradeResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.TradeBinSubject) ||
            TradeResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.TradesSubject) ||
            MiniTickerResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.MiniTickerSubject) ||
            BookTickerResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.BookTickerSubject) ||
            KlineResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.KlineSubject);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what perspective are you looking for a review?

Comment: @PEterCsala, thank you for your comment! I was looking at other codes on GitHub and they used `switch` instead of that abstraction of mine in `HandleObjectMessage`. Here is an example: https://github.com/JuliaZaborowska/TPUM/blob/0bb2ed8583223187c695b8f6cf9c1312b4ddd689/TPUM/PresentationLayer/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs#L210. In other words, the code review I want is only over `HandleObjectMessage` and TickerResponse's `TryHandle`

Comment: I improved the question, so it's clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `TryHandle`

- First of all I would not trust the input parameters. I suggest to make sure that they are not `null` before you start accessing their members (like `response.RootElement`)
- As far as I know the `GetProperty` [throws KeyNotFoundException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getproperty?view=net-6.0#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_GetProperty_System_String_) if a given key is not present
- The `GetString` might [throw an InvalidOperationException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getstring?view=net-6.0) if the `JsonElement`'s `ValueKind` is neither `String` nor `Null`
- `ToLower().EndsWith`: Depending on  how often this method is called, a [complied regex](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regexoptions-compiled) might provide better performance
- As far I know `JsonDocument` does not have neither `ToObject` method nor extension method. Is it a custom built solution, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138793/system-text-json-jsonelement-toobject-workaround)?

#### `HandleObjectMessage`

- At the first glance the single return statement seems a bit weird
- Let me show you an alternative where the actions and their relation are separated

```
var probes = new Func<bool>[]
{
    () =>  AggregateTradeResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.TradeBinSubject),
    () => TradeResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.TradesSubject),
    () => MiniTickerResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.MiniTickerSubject),
    () => BookTickerResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.BookTickerSubject),
    () => KlineResponse.TryHandle(response, Streams.KlineSubject)
};

return probes.Any(probe => probe());
```

- So, here we have defined several probe methods
- Then we iterate through them until we find one where the probe passes or until we run out of options
- With this approach the return statement is simple and easy to understand.

---

**UPDATE #1**: avoid closure

In order to capture the  `response`  in a closure you can do the following:

```
var probes = new Func<JsonDocument, bool>[]
{
    (res) =>  AggregateTradeResponse.TryHandle(res, Streams.TradeBinSubject),
    (res) => TradeResponse.TryHandle(res, Streams.TradesSubject),
    (res) => MiniTickerResponse.TryHandle(res, Streams.MiniTickerSubject),
    (res) => BookTickerResponse.TryHandle(res, Streams.BookTickerSubject),
    (res) => KlineResponse.TryHandle(res, Streams.KlineSubject)
};

return probes.Any(probe => probe(response));
```